# How to get the average number of words in files using the output of "wc -w"

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, wc

I'm listing the number of words in a bunch of files and sorting it like this:

`wc -w *.tex | sort -rn`

which outputs a nice list of the files and word count for each file

```
   17423 total
    6481 panama-to-colombia.tex
    5516 the-salt-flats.tex
    5426 hiking-cordillera-huayhuash.tex
```

How can I also calculate and display the average number of words per file?
i.e. a line at the bottom like:

`5808 AVERAGE`

Note: I'd like to find a solution that works for an arbitrary number of files in the list.

Comment: something like `... | sort -rn | awk 'NR==1{tot=$1;print;next}{linec++;print}END{print tot/linec " AVERAGE"}'` should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to append to your code:

```
| awk '{sum=sum+$1; print};END{print sum/2/(NR-1),"AVERAGE"}'
```

`sum=sum+$1` adds the number in the first column (`$1`) to the variable `sum` in each row. `print` outputs the current row unchanged. The average is calculated after the last line read in. During the calculation, please note that the line with `total` is also included in the output of `wc -w *.tex`.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: That would give a divide by zero error if `*.tex` expanded to just 1 file since then there'd be no `total` line.

Answer (score 3):

You can do entirely in awk:

```
awk 'FNR==1{files[FILENAME]=0}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) files[FILENAME]++}
END{for ( f in files ) {
    total+=files[f]
    print files[f], f }
    print total, "total"
    print total / (length(files)), "average"
}
' *.tex
```

Prints:

```
5426 hiking-cordillera-huayhuash.tex
5516 the-salt-flats.tex
6481 panama-to-colombia.tex
17423 total
5807.67 average
```

Comment: That won't quite behave the same way as `wc` as it'll treat empty files and repeated file names differently. It'll ignore empty files and treat the same file name appearing twice as if it was 1 file with twice the number of words while `wc -w` would display `0` for empty files and treat duplicate file names like separate files.

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -w --total=never *.tex | datamash -W mean 1
5807.6666666667
```

If you prefer a rounded result, e.g., to 2 decimal places:

```
wc -w --total=never *.tex | datamash -WR2 mean 1
5807.67
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all in awk, e.g. given these input files which includes an empty file (`fileempty`) and a repeated file (`file1`) which are 2 of the possible rainy day cases likely to cause a potential solution to fail:

```
$ wc -w file1 fileempty file1
 2 file1
 0 fileempty
 2 file1
 4 total
```

and using GNU awk for `ARGIND`:

```
$ awk '
    {
        numWords[ARGIND] += NF
        tot += NF
    }
    END {
        fmt=" %" length(tot) "s %s\n"
        for ( i=1; i<=ARGIND; i++ ) {
            printf fmt, numWords[i]+0, ARGV[i]
        }
        printf fmt, tot+0, "total"
        printf printf fmt, tot / (ARGIND ? ARGIND : 1), "AVERAGE"
    }
' file1 fileempty file1
 2 file1
 0 fileempty
 2 file1
 4 total
 1.33333 AVERAGE
```

and just to show how that behaves for the other rainy day cases that come to mind:

1. Just 1 input file:

```
$ awk '
    {numWords[ARGIND] += NF; tot += NF} END{fmt=" %" length(tot) "s %s\n"; for (i=1; i<=ARGIND; i++) { printf fmt, numWords[i]+0, ARGV[i] }; printf fmt, tot+0, "total"; printf fmt, tot / (ARGIND ? ARGIND : 1), "AVERAGE" }
' file1
 2 file1
 2 total
 2 AVERAGE
```

2. An empty file as the only input:

```
$ awk '
    {numWords[ARGIND] += NF; tot += NF} END{fmt=" %" length(tot) "s %s\n"; for (i=1; i<=ARGIND; i++) { printf fmt, numWords[i]+0, ARGV[i] }; printf fmt, tot+0, "total"; printf fmt, tot / (ARGIND ? ARGIND : 1), "AVERAGE" }
' fileempty
 0 fileempty
 0 total
 0 AVERAGE
```

3. No input file, just input from stdin (this may or may not be the desired output, idk):

```
$ awk '
    {numWords[ARGIND] += NF; tot += NF} END{fmt=" %" length(tot) "s %s\n"; for (i=1; i<=ARGIND; i++) { printf fmt, numWords[i]+0, ARGV[i] }; printf fmt, tot+0, "total"; printf fmt, tot / (ARGIND ? ARGIND : 1), "AVERAGE" }
' <<!
> foo
> bar
> !
 2 total
 2 AVERAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a function (or a script) which counts the words of the concatenation of its file args `cat -- "$@"`, and then divides that by the number of its file args `$#`:

```bash
wc-wavg() { echo $(($(cat -- "$@" | wc -w) / $#)); }

wc-wavg *.tex
```